# XLib: How do I return to windowed mode once I make it full screen?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I was able to make my app go full screen, but I can't make it go back to the windowed mode with **borders visible**. I tried to call XDeleteProperty to clear out the settings for full screen but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How exactly did you make it fullscreen? Note that fullscreen is outside the scope of Xlib, you're probably using NETWM/EWMH or some hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using _NET_WM_STATE http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html#id2569140 then prior to mapping the window you set the property, but after mapping the window you have to send a client message and the window manager updates the property. Read the part of EWMH that starts "To change the state of a mapped window, a Client MUST send a _NET_WM_STATE client message to the root window..."

This is because once you map the window the window manager is in charge of maintaining its state, there would be a race if both the app and the WM could modify the property directly.

See the source code to a toolkit such as GTK+ for example code.